# Проверка, является ли число квадратом целого числа

Tags: python

Учитывая целое число, определите, является ли оно квадратным числом:

В математике квадратное число или идеальный квадрат — это целое число, являющееся квадратом целого числа; другими словами, это произведение некоторого целого числа на самого себя.

Примеры: `-1: False, 0: True, 25 True | CodeWars`

Первый вариант решения проходит все тесты, но не проходит по времени:

```
if n ==0:
    return True
else:
    for i in range(0,n):
        if i*i==n:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Второй вариант не проходит 3 теста (на 3, 26 и секретный):

```
if n == 0:
    return True
elif n<0:
    return False
else:
    if n ** 0.5 == 1: return False
    else: return True
```

Почему второй вариант не проходит данные тесты?

Нужен вариант, который занимает мало времени (не попадёт под ошибку `Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)`, а также не используются библиотеки.

Comment: if n ** 0.5 == 1 Что вы тут проверяете? 

Comment: Почему не просто что-нить типа `if ( (int) (n ** 0.5) ) ** 2 == n` ?

Comment: @Akina В питоне приводить к инту надо вызывая его как функцию, это не C# )  Но так то вопрос совершенно точный

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну  я про питон, кроме того что он существует, почти ничего и не знаю...

Comment: Если у вас питон 3.8: return math.isqrt(n) ** 2 == n

Comment: `(n**.5).is_integer()`

Comment: Зачем вы убрали цитирование с текста условия задачи?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Я где-то читал, что таким способом можно найти корень. Судя по тестам это правда, но видимо у этого метода есть исключения, либо я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: Корень (квадратный) найти можно. Но зачем вы его сравниваете с единицей?

Comment: @AlexeyTen мне рассказывали, что если сравнивать с нулём - это целые числа, а с еденицей соответственно наоборот. Иначе не знаю, каким образом проверить.

Comment: @Alexander_K Там наверное остаток от деления на 1 проверялся, есть и такой способ проверить, что число целое. Но это не то, что вы написали совсем.

Comment: @CrazyElf какой тогда использовать?

Comment: @Alexander_K Ну вот выше в комментариях `return (n**.5).is_integer()` хороший способ и понятый

Comment: @CrazyElf Не подходит, изменил часть кода, но теперь проходит всего 2 теста из 6.

Comment: Если вы просто подставили вместо того условия, то понятно. Я чуть поправил код, там просто `return` этой проверки нужно делать

Comment: Ура, победа! Переставил возвраты bool.

Comment: Ну, как вариант, но вообще в большинстве случаев можно то, что в `if` проверяется прямо 
и возвращать, без всякого `if`, это уже нужный `bool`

Comment: @SergFSM, погрешность округления вполне может дать int.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/295579/4928642

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет смысла делать цикл до `n`. Это примерно 100500 лишних операций в среднем. Если `n` равно 10001, то получится 9900 лишних итераций, ведь квадрат любого числа больше 100 уже больше 10000, так зачем их проверять. Нужно делать цикл до квадратного корня из `n`

```
if n == 0:
    return True
else:
    for i in range(n + 1):
        i2 = i * i # квадрат очередного числа
        if i2 == n:
            return True
        elif i2 > n: # если квадрат больше n, то нет смысла проверять дальше
            break
return False # тут я убрал else и перенес строчку на уровень выше. Разницы никакой нет, а читаемость улучшилась.
```

Прибавление 1 позволяет убрать первую проверку на 0. Так что мы эту проверку лучше заменим на проверку отрицательных чисел:

```
if n < 0:
    return False
else:
    for i in range(n + 1):
        i2 = i * i
        if i2 == n:
            return True
        elif i2 > n:
            break
return False
```

Comment: Прежде чем я воспользуюсь функцией math.sqrt(), мне придётся совершить import, что запрещено.

Comment: Ну сорян, в условиях этого не написано ‍♂️

Comment: Да вообще непонятно, зачем нужен цикл, если можно просто взять корень и проверить, что он целый )

Comment: Дописал, а так же попробовал брать 2 - n, время сократилось на 0.04ms в тесте, но этого недостаточно.

Comment: исправил на без квадратного корня

Answer (score 3):

Простейшее быстрое решение для любого целого числа - двоичный поиск для получения целой части квадратного корня и прямая проверка что его квадрат равен исходному числу:

```
def isqrt(n):
    low = 0
    high = n + 1 # + 1 to process 0, 1 properly
    
    while low < high - 1:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if n < mid ** 2:
            high = mid
        else:
            low = mid

    return low


def is_square(n):
    return n >= 0 and isqrt(n) ** 2 == n
```

Answer (score 1):

Приведу, как ответ, так как часто сам сталкиваюсь с таким в задачах, а в комментариях именно этого способа не вижу. Хотя, если у вас случай именно для простого возведения в степень, то здесь вариант ниже не поможет. А вот в ряде схожих случаев будет просто необходим.
Спасибо @CrazyElf за очень ценный комментарий к первому варианту ответа.

Использование оператора возведения в степень `**` и деления по модулю `%` (а они часто используются вместе, при хэшировании, например) обычно затратно по времени при больших числах.
В этом случае лучше использовать встроенную функцию `pow`.

К примеру, в случае возведения трехзначного числа в трехзначную степень `**` ещё работает быстрее, чем `pow`, а вот для четырехзначных - уже наооброт. См. пример ниже сделанный на моем (далеко не самом новом) ноуте.

```
import timeit
import math

print(timeit.timeit ('pow(5362, 2445)')) # 142 секунды
print(timeit.timeit ('5362**2445'))      # 147 секунд

print(timeit.timeit ('(526 ** 252) % 10145')) # 2.87 секунды
print(timeit.timeit ('pow(526, 252, 10145)')) # 0.90 секунд
```

Особо важно это при всевозможных множественных применениях возведения в степень в программе, включая рекурсивные и т.д., т.е. при большом числе таких операций.

И вот интересная статья по этой теме: https://blog.finxter.com/a-guide-to-pythons-pow-function/

Примечание:
Есть ещё `pow` в библиотеке `math`, но с ним вообще что-то странное.
Например, `pow(53, 244)` считается без ошибок, а math.pow(53, 244) выдает `OverflowError: math range error`. Так что его тут не рассматриваю.

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Comment: А вы где-то тестировали? Вообще-то считается, что наоборот `**` быстрее, это даже по дизассемблированному коду видно. `pow` требует предварительного разрешения ссылки на функцию, а `**` использует встроенный метод, без этого лишнего этапа.

Comment: Перед использованием нужно ведь прописать 'import math'? Сам факт в том что в codewars нельзя использовать import и функции. Возможно я ошибаюсь, но я пытался и не смог.

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо большое! Вы правы для данного примера.  Переделаю ответ. Теперь вижу, что я лишь частично понимал, что и почему у меня получилось c `pow` - и теперь "картинка сложилась", а то непонятно было, зачем нам `**`. (на Stepik некоторые тесты только так и можно пройти. Несколько часов потратил тогда, как помню, прежде, чем сделал).

Comment: @Сергей, ** быстрее. Таймер показал, что ваш метод выполняется за 0.12ms, ** за 0,07ms

Comment: Александр, да, быстрее в данном случае. См. мой комментарий выше к CrazyElf. Но будут случаи, когда он будет очень важен, я обновлю ответ ещё. И да, никакого `math` не нужно для `pow`.

Comment: Сергей, уже увидел спасибо, но во втором коде дело не в скорости, а в самой ошибке в случаях с числами 3 и 26.

Comment: `math.pow` и просто `pow` это разные функции. и math.pow работает быстрее встроенной. Вообще для получения конкретно квадратного корня самым быстрым способом будет `math.sqrt()`.

`timeit('pow(val, p)', setup='import math; val=625; p=0.5', number=10_000_000_0)`
9.423890197998844
`timeit('math.pow(val, p)', setup='import math; val=625; p=0.5', number=10_000_000_0)`
8.183318900999438
`timeit('val ** p', setup='import math; val=625; p=0.5', number=10_000_000_0)`
7.0028045600010955
`timeit('math.sqrt(val)', setup='import math; val=625; p=0.5', number=10_000_000_0)`
6.086620219000906

Comment: @NEStenerusnester, спасибо. С `math.pow` у меня вообще что-то странное - см. примечание к моему ответу. Это у всех так?

Comment: Александр, если вы продолжите изучение Python, то на курсах по алгоритмах или структурах данных вам понадобится `pow`, так что обновил ответ, раз уж начал отвечать:-)

Comment: `math.pow` дает ошибку, потому что `pow` из модуля math получает аргументы, которые под капотом переводятся в обычный Cи'шный double. Максимальное значение, которое вы можете получить таким образом примерно составляет 10^308, в то  время как встроенный `pow` и `**` работают прямо в float объектом питона, который не имеет таких ограничений, потому что устроен совсем иначе

Comment: @NEStenerusnester, чтo-то странное с вашим кодом. Выдает мне `TypeError: 'module' object is not callable` на первую же строку `timeit('pow(val, p)', setup='import math; val=625; p=0.5', number=100000000)`,

Comment: вы сделали `import timeit`, а нужно `from timeit import timeit`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137565/discussion-between-nestenerus-nester-and-).

Comment: Мое утверждение про Си'шный double можно легко подтвердить, взглянув на исходный код python: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c7163a7f7cd2/Modules/mathmodule.c#l1781

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for i in range(0,n):
> ```

Такая проверка получается за O(n).

1. Можно сделать цикл с условием `i*i <= n`, тогда станет O(sqrt(n))
2. Можно использовать бинпоиск и получить O(lb(n))
3. Если диапазон значений позволяет (результат не бесконечность), то можно извлечь квадратный корень, получить вещественное число, вычислить, насколько отличаются следующее и предыдущие числа (при больших значениях будет не на 1), после чего сделать цикл или бинпоиск по получившемуся диапазону.
4. Можно реализовать алгоритм вычисления квадратного корня столбиком самостоятельно. Это будет работать даже если предполагается, что входные числа очень большие.